# Elementary proof that $c^n > n^c$ for $n>>1$?

Tags: analysis, inequality

I need to prove that for $c>1$ we can find some bound $n_0$ such that $c^n>n^c$ for all $n\in \mathbb N, n > n_0$.

Now all proofs I found so far include more advanced tools like that $f(x) = x/\log x$ grows unbounded, and to prove that we need again more theory. Is there a more elementary proof of this statement that does not get too long? The reason is that I want to show it a student that just started taking math courses at a university.

Comment: I am trying to settle it with simple inequalities and binomial theorem only but it is hard, it looks the more elementary the proof the more involved it becomes.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove pretty easily without much theory $\frac{\log x}{x}\to 0$ as $x\to\infty,$ if you know $\log u\leq u$. Then for $x>1$:

$$0\leq \frac{\log \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}\leq 1$$

But $\log\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}$. Multiplying by $\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$ you get:

$$0\leq \frac{\log x}{x}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Knowing that $\log u \leq u$ is exactly equivalent to proving the OPs problem in the first place.

Comment: No, it really is not. You need more than that. You need that $\frac{\log c}{c}>\frac{\log n}{n}$ for $n$ large. @xyzzyz

Answer (score 1):

Write $n=(1+m)c$.

$c^n>n^c$ is equivalent to $c^m>m+1$.

Now use the inequality $$
\begin{align*}
c^m\geq c^{\lfloor m\rfloor}&\geq 1+(c-1)\lfloor m\rfloor+(c-1)^2\lfloor m\rfloor(\lfloor m\rfloor-1)/2\\
&\geq 1+(c-1)(m-1)+(c-1)^2(m-1)(m-2)/2\\
&>1+(c-1)(m-1)+2(m-1)\\
&>1+2(m-1)\\
&>1+m,
\end{align*}
$$ 
Whenever $m>2+\frac{4}{(c-1)^2}$.

Comment: You have to be very careful with the power series for $(1+x)^m$ when $m$ is not an integer, because some of the later coefficients can be negative.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to prove that for $c>1$ we can find some bound $n_0$ such that
>   $c^n>n^c$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N},n>n_0$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{c^n}{n^c}=\infty\quad (*)$$
Indeed as $ \lceil c\rceil\ge c$ then $\dfrac{c^n}{n^{\lceil c\rceil }}\le \dfrac{c^n}{n^c}$ and applying L'Hopital rule $\lceil c\rceil $ times as $c>1$ we get $\dfrac{c^n \log^{\lceil c\rceil}  c}{\lceil c\rceil !}\to\infty \text{ as } n\to\infty$

Thus if the LHS of the inequality tends to $\infty$ then to a greater extent does the RHS. So $(*)$ is proved.

This means that for any $M>0$ there exists an $\bar n$ such that for $n>\bar n$ it happens that $\dfrac{c^n}{n^c}>M$. I choose $M=1$ so that there exists an $n_0$ such that for $n>n_0$ we have $\dfrac{c^n}{n^c}>1$ that is $c^n>n^c$

*QED*

Comment: Ceiling of 1.5 is 2 and $2^n>n^2$ for n greater than 2

Comment: @flawr I changed completely my proof. Now it works and it's easy to understand. Hope it helps